# Selenium - Safari facebook login error using Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm currently learning selenium automation using Java and I am trying to perform automated facebook login os Safari 14.0.2 on MacOS Big Sur.

I've written this code - this code is working on Google Chrome, I am successfully logged in.

Script:

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();


driver.get("https://facebook.com");

driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("email");  //real credentials in selenium

driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("password"); //real credentials in selenium

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Prijať všetky']")).click();  //accept cookies pop-up

driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
```

Everything is going as expected until the last step - click on login button. I am getting this error in console:

```
jan 06, 2021 8:18:40 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'AiruzivelaFilip', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:107f:1f90:9115:b77a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: Safari, browserVersion: 14.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, safari:automaticInspection: false, safari:automaticProfiling: false, safari:diagnose: false, safari:platformBuildVersion: 20C69, safari:platformVersion: 11.1, safari:useSimulator: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, webkit:WebRTC: {DisableICECandidateFiltering: false, DisableInsecureMediaCapture: false}}
Session ID: 01189D0B-44EA-4458-B9C5-FE8050AEC11C
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
at safariTest.main(safariTest.java:17)
```

Can you please hint me the solution or where can I find the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're using Java 15, and the code is trying to call a constructor which isn't valid. Suggest try re-running it on Java 11 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I've actually solved it by switching the steps: 1. load webpage 2. wait for cookies pop up to appear and be clickable 3. click on accept 4. insert credentials 5. click login. Safari somehow couldn't 't handle the flow as same as chrome where the original code works.